# Replace Windows Calendar with Google Calendar?

Tags: windows, notification-area, google-calendar, windows-10-calendar-app

When I click the windows 10 clock, it shows a popup calendar. Is there a way to have my google calendar/agenda events in there? Or maybe an app that replaces the windows clock with this function? Something like the android widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your Google Calendar to the Windows Calendar app, do the following:

- Click Start, find the Calendar app and open it.
- To add your Google account, click Settings (gear icon, bottom left-hand corner) > Manage Accounts > Add Account.
- The app will prompt you to select your account provider.
  Click Google and fill in your credentials.
- Click Next as needed until done.

You should now see all your Google Calendars listed under "Gmail" in the
left-hand panel of the app’s main screen, where you can select your account.
You may edit appointments and add new entries in the Windows Calendar app,
and the Windows Calendar will show your Gmail Calendar.